# How do you render the viewport view in Cycles?

Tags: rendering, 3d-view, camera

Everytime I click the render viewport, it just renders without the cycles engine and it renders all the UI symbols in the edit scene.

Appreciate any suggestions.

Comment: can you share a screenshot of your problem?

Comment: That's what it's supposed to do. Could you tell me what difference do you want to achieve by rendering VP that you couldn't by hitting F12?